# How to make this effect that the light of lantern being translucent? (Japanese lantern)

Tags: texturing, unreal-engine

I'd like to make this type of Japanese lantern. The modeling is quite easy but texturing is bugging me. Eventually I wish it could be exported to Unreal Engine. I don't know whether it could be done in texturing process or have to be done in UE. Need some help please.

[image]

Comment: so is it supposed to work with Cycles or Eevee?

Answer (score 2):

A simple mix between *Diffuse* and *Translucent* seems to work fine in both Eevee and Cycles. Make it a bit more subtle with an *Image Texture* and *Noise* nodes etc...

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thanks. But it needs to have a light source within the object which gives more impact on performance. I'm thinking is there a way that uses emissive map to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate? Maybe edit your question. Also, there's a light in my object

Comment: To my limited knowledge, if a scene has too many lighting sources could cause low fps in real time rendering or taking too long for bake if not real time rendering. So I wish to use emissive map to achieve fake lighting effect (even though I'm not very sure that emissive map does better performance but I did see some articles saying that)

Comment: do you mean you want to put a sphere inside the box that will be emissive? or do you mean that you want the texture of the box itself to be emissive?

Comment: it could be a sphere inside the box or some part of the box being extruded up from bottom being emissive. Thanks to your answer I figured it out it seems only able to work with two materials in blender but probably just one in substance painter. The box simply need to have some "Transmission" value in the Principle BSDF and the inner glowing thing using anther material with Emission BSDF, and change render engine to Cycles(EVEEE doesn't work out).

Comment: probably some pictures will explain better

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to say that the outer box Principle BSDF needs to change the first value to "Multiscatter GGX" and set the inner emissive object emission strength to a high value.

[image]
[image]